# Flatten output of table whilst retaining names

Tags: r

**How can I flatten the output of R's `base::table` function (applied to columns of a dataframe) in order to return an `integer` vector with names according to the convention specified below?**

```r
set.seed(123); N <- 100
df <- data.frame(A = sample(c("GOOD", "BAD"), N, TRUE, c(0.4, 0.6)), 
                 B = sample(c("GOOD", "BAD"), N, TRUE, c(0.7, 0.3)))
table(df)
#       B
# A      BAD GOOD
# BAD   16   44
# GOOD  10   30

# Desired output (naming convention: A-B)
# BAD-BAD  GOOD-BAD  BAD-GOOD  GOOD-GOOD
#      16        10        44         30
```

Using `as.vector(table(df))` drops names, which I'd like to retain in one step for use downstream for example, in case the ordering of factors changes or to enable "toggling" of `useNA = "always"` when calling table whilst not having to manually track the positions of the respective cells in the output vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory (currently no access to R):

```
table(interaction(df$A, df$B, sep = "-"))
```

Could be that you need to specify the correct separator to `interaction`

Comment: That's correct. Add `sep = "-"` for the right naming.

Comment: +1 and Accepted. Thanks. Use of `interaction` also has the advantage that an `NA` in either column propagates to the interaction term, rendering the flattened output table with only one additional cell for any `NA` combination.

Comment: @Maël added the argument